# Amazon AWS Code Deploy deploy last successful revision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I deploy last successful revision using Amazon Code Deploy configured along with Autoscale group?

I have a setup where I can deploy code manually from bitbucket using AWS Deploy addon. Once Autoscale spin a server I am manually able to deploy the code, but during bootup it just won't push the last successful revision.

AWS Code deploy documentation is not very clear about or may be I am not able to understand it correctly?

Here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/ "Under the Hood" section it mentions it, but I am not able to pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it myself. To automatically deploy to an Autoscale group from Tag Type menu, while creating the deployment group "Auto Scaling Group" needs to be selected, and then in the Key choose the actual autoscale group. Code Deploy is smart enought and will pull all the instances associated with the selected AutoScale group.

[image]